# [Unity-Windows-Build]Cannot find type 'X' in module 'Y'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, unity-game-engine

I am building a project for Windows Phone (8.1) in Unity. I have installed Windows SDK 8.1, MS VS 2013 and I have required .NET frameworks installed in my Windows 8.1 Laptop.

When I build the project in Unity, it gives me VS .sln project. I opened it in VS 2013 and tried to build it. But, I am getting a error i.e.

> Cannot find type System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm in module mscorlib.dll

I have read posts about this kind of error and those didn't serve my purpose because I didn't import the **mentioned namespace** in the error in anywhere of the Unity Project. I searched in the plugins too.

I also changed the target framework in MonoDevelop to 4.5. I am using Unity 5.3 and MonoDevelop as IDE.

Any Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have antivirus?

Comment: I think you need to modify your build settings in Unity. Not sure how it works for windows builds but there should be a tick or drop-down list that lets you strip the engine code from the build. you should disable that option and try again. hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please clarify when the error occurs (build time or runtime, if runtime, exactly when). Does the same problem occur with a totally empty test project? Do you use any third party libraries?

Comment: The problem occurs in build time. Other project builds correctly. Yes, I am using Facebook and Google Play Games services in my game.